# Booking a flight in the airport right before departure

Tags: air-travel, thailand, bangkok

I'll be making a trip through Thailand and I only have 18 days. I already booked a flight to Chiang Mai and a flight from Bangkok back home. I'm also going to book a flight from Bangkok to Ko Samui and back to Bangkok right before my flight back home. I haven't booked the flight to Ko Samui yet because I'm not sure how long I will stay in Chiang Mai and in Bangkok, so I don't know the date yet. I know there are a lot of flights between Bangkok and Ko Samui, so...

Is it possible and advised to just go to the airport in Bangkok and **buy a ticket there to fly to Ko Samui already a few hours later** (and the same for returning)? Or would you discourage to do this and advise me to just pick a date of departure and book this flight already?

Some advice?

Comment: When are you traveling?  Time of year makes a big difference in last minute availability.

Comment: @Tom From July 9 until July 27

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you are visiting during the low season (or green season as many call it since it is also rainy season), most flights will not sell out in advance.

But that said, there is only one flight each day direct from Chiang Mai to Koh Samui, so if you plan to use that flight, then booking ahead might be a good idea.  If you plan to stop in Bangkok enroute from CM to KS, then there are numerous daily flights to Koh Samui, as well as several flights to Surat Thani from where you can catch a ferry to KS.

All of the domestic airlines do have online booking, so as soon as you decide your date, you can book the flight before going to the airport (better than sitting around for hours at the airport if the early flights are full).

Comment: Yes, I'll be flying from Bangkok, because I'll visit Chiang Mai first. Okay so it's possible, but better/easier to book it just a few days in advance when I'm in Bangkok. But will there be a difference of price when buying a ticket at the airport?

Comment: Domestic flights in Thailand tend to be divided into 3 or 4 fare buckets based on seat quantity not time. So on any given flight there maybe 10 seats at the lowest fare, 20 at the next higher fare, 30 at the next and the rest at full fare (random numbers not actual counts). There aren't advance purchase discounts nor airport surcharges, so the price you see online or at the airport will simply be what ever fare bucket has seats. The only advantage of booking ahead online is being able to go the airport when you need to, not having to go early then wait for whatever flight has seats.

Comment: Okay thanks for clearing that out. Also thanks for telling about Surat Thani, because I searched this flight and it happens to be €220 cheaper (incl return) and I bet it will be nice to take a ferry there! I'll only have to find out how to get to Donsak for the ferry apparently

Comment: The ferry companies (SeaTran & Lomprayah) have travel desks at Surat Thani Airport, so you can book the ferry ticket and transfer to the docks through them. You will want to check their websites before you book your flight to make sure you arrive in time to catch the ferry, as they don't run 24/7.